# Django database and authentication (and posting the data to a dashbaord)

Tags: html, django, authentication

I have a register and login page, all formatted how its supposed to, and the register data fields are stored in variables on django. When a user gets to the login page, I want to be able to check if the user and password combination is a match. If they are, then it shows the data that goes along with the user on a dashbaord page, but if they dont match, it sends them to an error page.

Edit: This is my code so far https://bitbucket.org/kunaladhia01/studentaccounts/src
Thanks in advance

Comment: the most primitive way is - you need to have a database table where you can store the username and password and another table to store data related to a particular user. Once you authorize the user credentials, look for that user's related data in the second table and display them. 

Note: You have to be more clear on your question, with snippets of what you have done !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make a home made solution for authentication. Django comes with support for [user authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/).

> Django comes with a user authentication system. It handles user
>   accounts, groups, permissions and cookie-based user sessions. This
>   section of the documentation explains how the default implementation
>   works out of the box, as well as how to extend and customize it to
>   suit your project’s needs.

At the same time django's support for registration isn't all that great. THere are lots of popular packages for that such as django-allauth and django-registration.